# Inserting wrong values while sp being invoked through java

Tags: java, sybase

I was trying to insert a Numeric(9,2) value in Sybase database through SP which is being invoked through Java. But while passing 8789.22 through java, the SP is inserting 8789.00 in the table.

Comment: Can you share your problematic code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was using Double, but I tried using BigDecimal and it worked.

### Example:

```
Double amt = 2408.22;
BigDecimal bAmt = new BigDecimal(amt);
bAmt = bAmt.SetScale(2,RoundingMode.CEILING);
/* since the data type of amt in sp is Numeric(9,2)*/
/* The SP call was made here with bAmt as input parameter. */
```

If you do not scale it to round of to 2 decimal places then it might not work.